# Copying tables from one database to another on same server

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

As the server requires a connection for each database, the answers I've found in SO don't work at all. 
For some tables I have to make some calculations before copying the rows, but some I can copy whole table. And finally it's an automation in my program that I've wrote.

Oldcn is the connection to old database, Newcn for the new database.

For the tables that I can copy whole I wrote this procedure below.

Is there a better an short way to do this job? (It works on background)

```
    private string[] CopyTva(MySqlConnection Oldcn, MySqlConnection Newcn, string[] res, DoWorkEventArgs we,string msg)
    {
        int counter = int.Parse(res[1]);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tvaval", Oldcn);
        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tvaval (id,tvavalue,cr_user,cr_date,up_user,up_date) VALUES (@id,@tvavalue,@cr_user,@cr_date,@up_user,@up_date)", Newcn);
        MySqlDataReader rd = null;
        try
        {
            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", rd["id"].ToString());
                //bla bla same as above
                try
                {
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (MySqlException e)
                {
                    rd.Dispose();
                    res[2] = "Erreur:TVA " + e.Message.ToString();
                    return res;
                }
                ++counter;
                bgw.ReportProgress((counter * 100) / DbTotalRow,msg);
                cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
            }
            rd.Dispose();
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            res[2] = "Erreur:TVA " + e.Message.ToString();
            return res;
        }
        res[0] = "1";res[1] = counter.ToString();res[2] = ""; 
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: when do you dispose of the 2 remaining `MySqlCommand` objects.. try wrapping those around a `using(){}`

Comment: I have one read and dispose is at the and of while loop. As the connections are open during whole transfer I didn't use using statement here. But I know it's a good solution. Thanks

Comment: you know that auto disposing is not happening on the sql objects..

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't require a separate connection for each database. A connection has a default database, but you're allowed to specify the database name explicitly before the table name, and this will override the default. So you can do this with a single query:

```
INSERT INTO newdb.tvaval 
SELECT * FROM olddb.tvaval
```

Comment: How do I configure this ?
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO " + NewDbName + "." + tblName + " SELECT * FROM " + Pv.DbName + "." + tblName, Oldcn))
When I try this query, I get this MySqlException: {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: INSERT command denied to user 'bodrum2015'@'XX.XXX.XX.XX' for table 'def_firme' 
Because I tried to insert in another database with a connection not realised. If I do same in localhost it works.

Comment: You need to grant `INSERT` permission to `bodrum2015@x.x.x.x` in the new DB.

Comment: Are you using different connections because they have different username information for each database?

Comment: Yes! One database is bodrum2015.db.blabla.com other is bodrum2016.db.blabla.com on the same shared server.

Comment: But when you create the connections, do you have to use different usernames for each? Can you create a single username that has access to both databases?

Comment: Yes for the connection I have same pass and same username.

Comment: Then I don't know why you're getting that error message. Either the username has permission to insert into the new table or it doesn't, it doesn't matter which connection is used.

Comment: Godaddy shared database servers let only a read only user for common username and does not give insert or delete update rights

Comment: Can the user with INSERT rights for the new DB read from the old DB?